# getting bubble function to run

Tags: python, python-3.7, bubble-sort

I am trying to use python to make a list using user input and then I want to sort the list using a bubble function, but when I run the code I get an error saying function has no attribute homework3. can someone help get the code to run and sort the list?

```
def bubble(list):
    index_length=len(list)-1
    sorted= False

    while not sorted:
        sorted=  True
        for i in range (0,index_length):
            if list[i]>list[i+1]:
                sorted=False 
                list[i],list[i+1]=list[i+1], list[i]
    return list

homework3=[]

number_value=int(input('How many numbers do you want to sort?:'))
for j in range(number_value):
    value=int(input('Please enter your number value then press enter:'))
    homework3.append(value)
    print()
print(bubble.homework3)
```

Comment: Calling "bubble" should be written in a similar way as calling all the previous functions like "input" or "print".

Comment: Do not name your code objects (like argument `list` of the function named `bubble`) after builtin python types and functions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the code looks good for bubble sort. But not sure why you are doing `print(bubble.homework3)`. Instead use

```
print(bubble(homework3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call function like this: -
bubble(homework3)
change the syntax to this and it'll work